# How to get any specific key of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am a beginner. I am learning python. As stated in the question I want to print any specific key of any defined dictionary. Not all keys by `dict.keys()`.
If I have a the code:

```
My_dict={'name'='Carl','age'=24}
```

I want to print "name" only.
How to do it?

Comment: `My_dict["name"]` or `My_dict.get("name")`

Comment: Hey! I want to print key not value dude!

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to print the key using value or any other methods.

Comment: Ok if what you want is print a key for given value then `[key for key, value in My_dict.items() if value=='Carl']`

Comment: I can't decide how to bade you thanks.

Comment: Thanks for helping me :)